# NDK Android compile various extension files

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to use native libraries in my Android project and I try compiling them. The error I found is caused from the incompatible file extensions. They are .c .h .m4 .y and others extensions.

here is a part of my Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi-v7a
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := openssl-0.9.7m
FILE_LIST       := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_MODULE))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := pbc-0.5.12
FILE_LIST       := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_MODULE))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := libbswabe-0.9
FILE_LIST       := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_MODULE))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := gmp-5.0.2
FILE_LIST       := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_MODULE))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := libpbc
FILE_LIST       := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_MODULE))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := m4-1.4.16
FILE_LIST       := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_MODULE))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := cpabe-0.11
FILE_LIST       := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_MODULE))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
# LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_MODULE    := PHRapp_Login_JNI
FILE_LIST       := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/$(LOCAL_MODULE))
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

when i compile in Eclipse, it warned that there are unsupported source file extensions for the module i described in Android.mk.
How should I do for the solution?

Comment: Why do you think those file extensions are "incompatible"? "Incompatible" with what?

Comment: Eclipse show the warning that "Unsupported file extension" when i build the apk.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$wildcard` to list all files in lib build directory is not a good practice. When you work with so many open source libraries it's much easier to prepare and use *[standalone toolchain](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk.git/+/master/docs/text/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.text)* for NDK instead of improvizing the `Android.mk`.